# More filter options on admin/content

Tags: views, 8

Is there a way to have more/advanced filters on `https://example.com/admin/content` using Drupal 8? Like filtering for taxonomy terms or fields for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Now that Views is integrated into Drupal 8, the `admin/content` display can be driven by a customizable View.

Make sure the **Views**/**Views UI** module is enabled in `admin/modules`, then navigate to `admin/structure/views`. You'll see a View named **Content** which corresponds with `admin/content`. You can edit that view to add various exposed filters that correspond with your own content setup (e.g. custom taxonomy filtering).